# php array loop with an array loop to find values

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have a two-dimensional array $array_userinfo with approx. 21,000 elements. Each element has 'login' in first position and 'email' in the second position. What I need to do is to loop through this array and find any matching 'login' from another $array_usermeetingfolder, which is a one dimensional array with approx. 700 elements.

Here are the two arrays populated:

```
foreach ($child->children() as $node_principalid) {
array_userinfo[$i][0] = (string) $node_principalid->login;
$array_userinfo[$i][1] = (string) $node_principalid->email;
i++;                            
}

foreach (.......) {
$endusersconame =  (string) $usermeetingsfoldersco->children()->name;       
$array_usermeetingfolder[$j] = $endusersconame;//
 $j++;
}
```

What is the best/efficient way way to do this? I have a loop like this:

```
for ($k=0;$k < count($array_userinfo);$k++) {
//tempecho($array_userinfo[$k][0]);//will yield login, such as, 'joeblow'
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: what do you need in the end? I would do something like array_intersect(array_map(function($a) {return $a['login']}), $array_usermeetingfolder);

Comment: In the end, if there is a match found in the smaller array then use the email from the larger array to pass on to a function to send email to the user

Comment: OP, instead of doing `for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)` I recommend calculating the count first and using the variable the array count is in - big performance increase.

Comment: @David Harris: Will do that later. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is possible you should use the login as an array key, then you can fast access the key and I think you don't need to think about performance. Arrays in PHP are Hashmaps and if you know the key you can access it fast if you have to check the whole array it takes a lot longer. If you can not change it, you should think about creating a data structure from the array to habe this performance increase. Don't know wether it's worth, measure it :)

like:

```
<?php
foreach($array_userinfo as $info) {
    $checkAgainst[$info[0]] = $info[1];
}

foreach($array_usermeetingfolder as $mail) {
    if(isset($checkAgainst[$mail]) {
        $return[$mail] = $checkAgainst[$mail];
    }
}

// use $return
```

Comment: Thanks again. I guess at this point I can simply use a code which will work! This will be an occasionally used admin application and it is the email part in the loop which could affect the efficiency issues, should they arise. Anyway, what is this code? A part of a function? what is $checkAgainst?

Comment: "By how do I 'transform' the $array_usermeetingfolder?" > $checkAgainst. I transformed your $array_userinfo into a fast to search into data structure. And you can do whatever you want with it. Use it as a method or function. Or use it inside a function. I used your nomenclature.

Comment: Not working. I have your code outside of a function; even after fixing some syntax errors in your code, I get an error: undefined index login, undefined index email. Sorry for being dense.

Comment: what is the name of your index where the mail is in? 0? and the login? 1 I thought because you wrote 'login' that this are the keys of your array

Comment: No, I never used the key approach. I think that's where the problems are coming up from your code: I used [$array_userinfo[$i][1] = (string) $node_principalid->email; $i++]; and [$array_usermeetingfolder[$j] = $endusersconame];// $j++; in two different loops. So both arrays values on index based.

Comment: I have just edited the original question and put both For loops in the code. HTH. Thanks!

Comment: oh, never mind, here is how that will work in your code: $checkAgainst[$info[0]] = $info[1];//0 is login, 1 is email

Comment: changed it. I hope it runs fast now :)

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

Transform the `$array_usermeetingfolder` so yuo have an array where the user logins are keys and values are anything. E.g.

```
$temp = array('joeblow' => 1,
      'someoneelse' => 1,
      ...);
```

Then in the loop you can just check if the key exists:

```
if (isset($temp[$array_userinfo[$k][0]]) {
    echo 'Hoozah!';
}
```

You can also use `array_key_exists()` instead of the isset. You will have to run some tests which is more efficient.

Comment: Michael, thanks. By how do I 'transform' the $array_usermeetingfolder? That array is being populated in another For Loop with something like:  $array_usermeetingfolder[$j] = $endusersconame; $j++;

Comment: oh. you were faster :-) Yes, do it that way!

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.

```
for($i=0;$i <= count($firstarray);$i++)
    {
    for ($j=0;$j <= count($secondarray);$j++)
    {
        while($firstarray[$i][0] == $secondarray[$j])
        {
            echo $firstarray[$i][0]; // or $secondarray[$j]
        }

    }



    }
```

Comment: This is a bad idea, you are iterating n*m times over the array keys. If you have 21.000 elements in the first array and 700 in the other: 21000*700=14.700.000 if you have 701: 14.721.000

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what's happening, as Fabian says.